# Схранение путей к файлам в БД php

Tags: php, sql, ajax

Это код обработчика который сохраняет файл на сервер в папку.
Мне нужно сохранить пути к этим файлам в БД, как мне это сделать, не могу понять к каким переменным обращаться

```
$data = array();

if( isset( $_GET['uploadfiles'] ) ){  
    $error = false;
    $files = array();

    $uploaddir = './uploads/'; // . - текущая папка где находится submit.php
    
    // Создадим папку если её нет
    if( ! is_dir( $uploaddir ) ) mkdir( $uploaddir, 0777 );

    // переместим файлы из временной директории в указанную
    foreach( $_FILES as $file ){
        if( move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . basename($file['name']) ) ){
            $files[] = realpath( $uploaddir . $file['name'] );
        }
        else{
            $error = true;
        }
    }
    
    $data = $error ? array('error' => 'Ошибка загрузки файлов.') : array('files' => $files );
    
    echo json_encode( $data )
```

Comment: Если вы собираетесь отображать в web то стоит сохранять путь относительно сервера. Т.е. `"http://www.ru/uploads".$_FILE['name']`

Comment: Ага, и если вдруг доменное имя или папка или протокол изменится - то всю таблицу придется апдейтить, умно!

Comment: Тогда вообще не вижу проблемы - сохраняйте просто имя файла. А полный путь указывайте в php/css файлах.

Comment: проблема в том что я не могу посроить SQL запрос ```$sql = 'INSERT INTO image_table ( Name ) VALUES (ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ КАКОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ УКАЗЫВАТЬ ЕСЛИ МНЕ НУЖНО ТОЛЬКО ИМЯ ФАЙЛА?)';```

Comment: Какой потенциал для загрузки вредоносных файлов..прям сказка. Вы прежде чем брать из интернета, почитайте нюансы загрузки файлов на сервер. Убедитесь, что нельзя загрузить исполняемый файл и т.п.. Иначе долго не проживете.